# How to make a share button to share quote with post URL in Google blogger blog

Tags: javascript, share, blogger, android-sharing

I want to make a share button to share quotes from my **blogger blog**.

For example

```
<blockquote>"Imagination is more important than knowledge."
--Albert Einstein</blockquote>
<share_button>

<blockquote>"Life is a preparation for the future; and the best preparation for the future is to live as if there were none."
--Albert Einstein</blockquote>
<share_button>
```

When visitors click the share button of any quote than the **related quotes** with **post URL** can be share to any app according to the **visitor choice** using default Android's share app list.

**Edit :-** My blog is based on only Quotes topic. Every post have many quotes and I want to use a share button after every quote so that people can share any quote they want.
How to do this without creating unique **ID** for every button and quotes ?

```
<blockquote>"Imagination is more important than knowledge."
--Albert Einstein</blockquote>
<button class="shareBtn">Share Blockquote</button>

<blockquote>"Life is a preparation for the future and the best preparation for the future is to live as if there were none."
--Albert Einstein</blockquote>
<button class="shareBtn">Share Blockquote</button>

  <blockquote>"Remember not only to say the right thing in the right place, but far more difficult still, to leave unsaid the wrong thing at the tempting moment."
--Benjamin Franklin</blockquote>
<button class="shareBtn">Share Blockquote</button>


  <blockquote>"You don't have to hold a position in order to be a leader."
--Henry Ford</blockquote>
<button class="shareBtn">Share Blockquote</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Web Share API](https://web.dev/web-share/)

```
<button id="shareBtn">Share Blockquote</button>

<script>
//<![CDATA[
var shareButton = document.getElementById('shareBtn');
var title = document.title;
var text = document.querySelector('blockquote').textContent;
var url = window.location.href;

shareButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (navigator.share) {
        navigator.share({
            title: title,
            text: text,
            url: url
        });
    }
});
//]]>
</script>
```

**Edit**: In case you have multiple quotes, `previousElementSibling` is perfect here but the share button should come after blockquote.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var title = document.title;
var url = window.location.href;

document.querySelectorAll('.shareBtn').forEach(function (btn) {
    var text = btn.previousElementSibling.textContent;
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (navigator.share) {
            navigator.share({
                title: title,
                text: text,
                url: url
            });
        }
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: your solution is working for only one quote or only for first button.

Comment: I want to use "class" instead of "id" for every button. edited the question

Comment: Thanks @Bassam for your help. Its working Just make a small correction in line document.querySelectorAll('shareBtn') Apply a  dot(.) before shareBtn

Comment: Code is working only when I add it inside the post. But not working if add in theme before </head> tag. Please check this url https://www.awalcreations.in/2019/12/happy-new-year-wishes.html?m=1

Comment: Hi beginner, That because JavaScript code executes before rendering blockquote elements on the page. It should come after elements. Why don't you place the code before </body> not </head> for best performance!

Comment: Thanks Bassam till now I used to think that JavaScript code should be place before </head>

Comment: How to add web.dev to my blog?