# How to customise alert when visitors copy something on clipboard

Tags: javascript, share, blogger, android-sharing

How to customise alert dialogue box when in visitors browser web share API method not work. [This is a link Questions with the post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363503/why-new-line-is-not-applied-when-copying-text-to-clipboard)

```
<script>
var title = document.title;
var url = window.location.href;

document.querySelectorAll('.shareBtn').forEach(function (btn) {
    var text = btn.previousElementSibling.textContent + '\n';
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (navigator.share) {
            navigator.share({
                title: title,
                text: text,
                url: url
            });
        }else{
                var shareText = document.createElement('textarea');
                document.body.appendChild(shareText)
                shareText.value = text+url;
                shareText.select();
                document.execCommand('copy',false);
                shareText.remove();
                alert(" Text Copied");
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to create something like most android app use to show notification after copy any text which disappears automatically in a second.

[image]

And is there any method to change automatically button text from **"Click to Share"**  to **"Click to Copy"** when Web browser not support Web Share API method.

```
<button id="shareBtn">Click to Share</button>
```

Comment: I think you can't customize `alert` boxes but you can listen for copy event and whenever that happens you can display a custom dialogue box or whatever you want.

Comment: can you suggest any article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hidden element with your desired style and show it after copying for 1 sec

**The second Part:** Change button text using this `btn.textContent`

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert-msg">Text Copied</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alert-msg {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var title = document.title;
var url = window.location.href;
var msgDiv = document.querySelector('.alert-msg');

document.querySelectorAll('.shareBtn').forEach(function (btn) {
    if (!navigator.share) { btn.textContent = 'Click to Copy'; }
    var text = btn.previousElementSibling.textContent + '\n';
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (navigator.share) {
            navigator.share({
                title: title,
                text: text,
                url: url
            });
        } else {
                var shareText = document.createElement('textarea');
                document.body.appendChild(shareText)
                shareText.value = text+url;
                shareText.select();
                document.execCommand('copy',false);
                shareText.remove();
                msgDiv.style.display = 'block';
                setTimeout(function () { msgDiv.style.display = 'none'; }, 1000);
            }
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```